# adding a animated image while jquery ajax is working

Tags: jquery, ajax, animated-gif

I am using Jquery Ajax, my code looks like this

```
 $.get(
    'GetPage.aspx',
    'url=' + url ,
    function (response) {
        if (!cancelNavigationFlag)
            setIframeHtml(response);
        cancelNavigationFlag = false;
    },
    'html'
);
```

I need to add a animated gif that will appear while the ajax is working and then disappear when the ajax finishes.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different logic and solution.

Set a div where you want the gif image to appear like `<div id="loader">`.

Next, Set it a background image in css and don't set the image link like;

`background: no-repeat center;`

and when ajax execute, give it a background image `loader.gif` and remove it when ajax task completes, like;

```
 $.get(
    $("#loader").css({ 'background-image':'url(images/loader.gif)' });
    'GetPage.aspx',
    'url=' + url ,
    function (response) {
        if (!cancelNavigationFlag)
            setIframeHtml(response);
        cancelNavigationFlag = false;
        $("#loader").css({ 'background-image':'url()' });
    },
    'html'
);
```

I have not tested it myself.. Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you. it worked for me. any ideas why it only works on firefox and not chrome?

Comment: Let me have a look at that.. Have you tested it in IE??

Comment: I didnt test IE cuz my site doesnt work on IE at all in this point.

Comment: are you using the latest version of chrome??

Comment: i am using this version 12.0.742.100

Answer (score 1):

I normally do something like this:

```
$("#indicatordiv").show();
$.post("somepage", function(result){ 
    $("#indicatordiv").hide();
})
```

Where "indicatordiv" is a simple div element containing the loader gif image.

So in your case, just ".show()" the element before the get request, and ".hide()" it inside the response function.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a div which contains an image tag with loader image. Initially hide the div. Before calling the ajax request show the div. and after getting data from ajax request hide the div.

```
$("#dvLoader").show();
$.get(
    'GetPage.aspx',
    'url=' + url ,
    function (response) {
        if (!cancelNavigationFlag)
            setIframeHtml(response);
        cancelNavigationFlag = false;
    },
    'html'
    success:
         function(data)
         {
            $("#dvLoader").hide();
         }

);
```

**dvLoader** contains an the loader image.

Comment: You have to show it again on the `$.get()` success callback. With this code the `#dvLoader` will hide after the `$.get()` gets called, not after the content has been loaded.